# How can I cache NFS shares on a local disk?

Tags: nfs

I use NFS to share media to computers around my house. Unfortunately one of the machines is on a slow wireless link, is there a way to cache network shares on the local disk for performance?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Stefan [led me down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4572/how-can-i-cache-nfs-shares-on-a-local-disk/4574#4574) the right track. This will work on any system 12.04 and newer.

Your filesystem will also need extended attribute support. If you're using EXT4 you're fine, if you're using EXT3 you'll need to ensure your filesystem is mounted with the `user_xattr` attribute.

Here's how I set it  up on the client machine, you don't need to do anything on the server side.

1. First, install the user space daemon:
   `sudo apt-get install cachefilesd`
2. Then turn it on by editing `/etc/default/cachefilesd` and changing the run line to `RUN=yes`
3. Ensure your NFS mount in `/etc/fstab` has an `fsc` option. Don't forget to remount it after you've made the changes. Here's my excerpt (modify to your needs):

   `192.168.1.115:/home/jorge /home/jorge/Backup nfs fsc`
4. Start the service: `sudo /etc/init.d/cachefilesd start`

Configuration of the cache is done in `/etc/cachefilesd.conf`, see the references for what the setting options are.

References:

- [Linux Magazine](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7378)
- `/usr/share/doc/cachefilesd/howto.txt.gz`
- `/usr/share/doc/cachefilesd/README.gz`
- [How do I enable extended attributes on ext4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124102/how-do-i-enable-extended-attributes-on-ext4)

Comment: Does it happen to know how to apply the same on `/etc/auto.master` ?

Comment: Be aware that there is a bug which can cause the `cachefilesd` daemon to run at 100% CPU: https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-cachefs/2014-February/msg00001.html https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=485314

Comment: At least as of Ubuntu 14.04, rw,hard are default, and intr is deprecated. So the only option you're using that has effect these days is fsc

Comment: @AndrewWagner Please submit an edit to the article!

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if there is any way to do this currently with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

However, the newer versions of the Linux kernel include a feature called [FS-Cache & CacheFS](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7378), which sounds exactly like what you (and I) want.

Also see [Local Caching For Network Filesystems](http://kerneltrap.org/taxonomy/term/985).

Comment: Thanks, it's a great feature. Unluckily it lacks write support :(.