# Ntfs mount locked after suspend

Tags: ntfs

Hopefully, I didn't miss this being asked by someone else, but I have an ntfs mount that gets locked up after I suspend my laptop.  Maybe it's because the wifi has to reconnect after starting up again?  But, even then if I try to umount and mount the drive it's still locked up.  I'm not sure where to even start looking into this one.  Anyone have some recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

This could be with the way you're mounting the share, you should perhaps try mounting it with the `soft` parameter on your laptop and see if that helps (update your question if it doesn't):

```
   soft / hard    Determines the recovery behavior of the NFS client after
                  an   NFS  request  times  out.   If  neither  option  is
                  specified (or if the  hard  option  is  specified),  NFS
                  requests  are  retried indefinitely.  If the soft option
                  is specified, then the NFS client fails an  NFS  request
                  after  retrans  retransmissions  have been sent, causing
                  the NFS  client  to  return  an  error  to  the  calling
                  application.

                  NB:  A  so-called  "soft"  timeout can cause silent data
                  corruption in certain  cases.  As  such,  use  the  soft
                  option only when client responsiveness is more important
                  than data integrity.  Using NFS over TCP  or  increasing
                  the value of the retrans option may mitigate some of the
                  risks of using the soft option.
```

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/nfs.5.html

The [NFS Faq on sourceforge](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s04.html) recommends using `intr` along with `hard` though, but I can't find a datestamp for the relevancy of this recommendation:

> soft
>
> If a file request fails, the NFS client will report an error to
>   the process on the client machine requesting the file access. Some
>   programs can handle this with composure, most won't. We do not
>   recommend using this setting; it is a recipe for corrupted files and
>   lost data. You should especially not use this for mail disks --- if
>   you value your mail, that is.
>
> hard
>
> The program accessing a file on a NFS mounted file system will
>   hang when the server crashes. The process cannot be interrupted or
>   killed (except by a "sure kill") unless you also specify intr. When
>   the NFS server is back online the program will continue undisturbed
>   from where it was. We recommend using hard,intr on all NFS mounted
>   file systems.

I personally use `soft` but I'm not doing a bunch of writing to the NFS server, I mostly use it as a client to consume things and don't touch the data much. YMMV, it's probably wise to try `intr` with `hard` first and see if that solves the problem.

See also:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/9499/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-hard-versus-soft-mounts-in-unix
- [Mounted NFS shares interrupting shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6654/mounted-nfs-shares-interrupting-shutdown)

Comment: Had a pretty stupid typo there, it's a nTfs mount not nfs.  However, I'm trying out hard,intr, but I also was changing some permissions to the mount as well, so we'll see if that helps.  Thank you

Comment: Ok, looks like it was either the permissions, or the hard,intr.  Cause it seems to be mounting up just fine now.  Thanks for your help.