# How do I enable extended attributes on ext4?

Tags: ext4, ceph

I want to experiment with Ceph, and it needs [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) enabled. How do I mount my filesystem with this support?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To enable extended attributes the `user_xattr` option in `/etc/fstab`

Example:

```
/dev/sda2  /media/mount_point  ext4  auto,users,user_xattr  0  2
```

You would then re-mount the partition.

and the man page :

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/attr.5.html
- I looked at the kernel configs [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/) and support for xattr is enabled by default , so no need for a custom kernel.
- [Discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8552524) on the Ubuntu Forums