# How do I enable extended attributes support on a wubi install?

Tags: wubi, ntfs, fstab, media, netflix

I am trying to install the [netflix-desktop app](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html) and when I start the app up, it shows me the error:

```
"Unable to set extended attribute: Operation not supported."
```

Ok, so I see the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124102/how-do-i-enable-extended-attributes-on-ext4), which tells me to edit `/etc/fstab`, and add the `user_xattr` option there. Seems simple.

But when I open my `/etc/fstab` (on a wubi install), I get the following:

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM 
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0
```

which looks quite different.

Should I still add the `user_xattr` option to sw, and remount?

Comment: What version of windows is your Linux installed in?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also and I just fixed it.
You need to add the line

```
/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk  /      ext3    loop,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0 1
```

to your `/etc/fstab`.

Then `sudo mount -o remount /`

Netflix on Ubuntu is AWESOME!