# Consistent dialog concerning wine-silverlight

Tags: wine, pipelight

I installed pipelight and as part of the installation procedure, after everything was done in terminal, an external window appeared and started automatically installing wine-silverlight. However, after several minutes of no progress, it seemed like that part of installation had crashed, eventually I just reboot my machine. Now whenever I launch my browser (I use Chromium, I realize that may be an issue?), I get the following messages:

```
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_1_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.1.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/scibor/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] GPU driver check - Your driver is supported, hardware acceleration enabled.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] using wine prefix directory /home/scibor/.wine-pipelight/.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[install-dependency] Downloading and running wine-silverlight5.1-installer.
[install-dependency] ERROR: Installer for wine-silverlight5.1-installer did not run correctly or was aborted.
[install-dependency] ERROR: Execution of wine-silverlight5.1-installer failed.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] basicplugin.c:346:checkPluginInstallation(): Plugin installer did not run correctly (exitcode = 1).
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] basicplugin.c:105:attach(): plugin not correctly installed - aborting.
```

So far I have only tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install wine-compholio wine-silverlight5.1-installer wine-mpg2splt-installer
```

But that has not resolved the issue. How can I prevent these messages from showing up? While this normally may seem trivial, these messages are accompanied by a dialog box showing up stating that wine-silverlight installation is underway, and I don't want that showing up with every launch of my browser. Furthermore, this happens not only on launch but every time I open up a new site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a problem can have multiple reasons. As its not clear what exactly the problem is in your case, I will describe solutions for the most common issues below.

**1. Previous installation was somehow interrupted and files are corrupt**

At first I would recommend to remove the whole wine prefix. This ensures that no corrupted files are left, which could prevent a proper installation.
First close all browser windows, then run (as a regular user, **not** root):

```
rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight
```

The folder will be recreated automatically and contains only Pipelight specific data, so don't worry about any lost data.
Afterwards start the browser window again, open *about:plugins*, and check if it works then.

**2. Outdated version of Pipelight or Wine-compholio**

If it still doesn't work you should make sure that your version of pipelight and wine-compholio is up to date. You can use

```
 dpkg --list | grep "\(pipelight\|wine-compholio\)"
```

to check that. Currently (at the time of writing) you should have wine-compholio >= 1.7.12 and pipelight >= 0.2.4.2.

**3. Unusual file system**

Wine only works properly when you run it from a "usual" file systems - I have already seen installations, where users were trying to run wine from an NTFS drive mounted via FUSE, or other unusual network drive configurations, where Silverlight cannot be installed properly.

The easiest way to find out the used file system is by manually taking a look at:

```
/etc/fstab
```

If the file system is either a network drive or some other unusual file system mounted via FUSE, then this is most likely the problem. If it is not possible to switch to different file system you can alternatively modify the Pipelight config files, such that the wineprefix is located on a different harddrive. Example instructions how to setup something like this:

```
cp /usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.1 ~/.config

# Open the new config file in an editor, for example gedit
gedit ~/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1

# search for "winePrefix = $HOME/.wine-pipelight/"
# modify it for example to "winePrefix = /media/secondhdd/.wine-pipelight/"
```

*Unrelated, but also very important:* To watch DRM protected content, the file system where the wine prefix is located also has to support XATTR (extended attributes), otherwise you'll get error N8156-6205! You can ignore this if you don't want to use Pipelight to watch DRM protected content.

The following commandline illustrates how to check for extended attributes in the home directory (the default location of the wine prefix):

```
# Run this once, such that setfattr and getfattr is installed
sudo apt-get install attr

# XATTR check, from: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Netflix/Pipelight
touch ~/.xattr_test && setfattr -n 'user.testAttr' -v 'attribute value' ~/.xattr_test &> /dev/null; getfattr ~/.xattr_test 2>&1 | grep -q user.testAttr && echo 'It works!' || echo 'No workie!'; rm ~/.xattr_test &> /dev/null
```

If the result is "No workie!" (and the attr package is installed) then you are missing XATTR in the home directory. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124102/how-do-i-enable-extended-attributes-on-ext4) is an example of how it can be enabled for ext4.

**4. If it still doesn't work ...**

To get rid of the annoying dialogs the easiest way is either to uninstall pipelight, or at least to disable the problematic plugins:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --disable silverlight

# if multiple plugins have problems:
# sudo pipelight-plugin --disable-all
```

Nevertheless this doesn't really solve the problem, but just hides the error. If you want to use Pipelight and need additional support, the fasted way is to ask someone in [#pipelight](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#pipelight) on IRC freenode (be a bit patient if noone responds immediately), or alternatively post a more detailed error description on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight) and we'll help you to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Browser is closed before installing in terminal to prevent crashing,I had a similar problem and had to abandon Chromium and switch to Chrome to make it go away.