# Cache NFS Shares on Local Disk through Virtual Machine

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, nfs, cache

I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to set up FS-Cache using CacheFS as the backend on a virtual machine which is using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit After following this tutorial to use cachefilesd,
[How can I cache NFS shares on a local disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4572/how-can-i-cache-nfs-shares-on-a-local-disk/4574#4574)
I setup the system for nfs sharing.  When running the cachefilesd daemon, it will pass the startup procedure and the dmesg will state:

FS-Cache: Cache "mycache" added (type cachefiles).
When running cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes I will get:

```
msali014@msali014-VirtualBox:~$ cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes 
NV SERVER   PORT DEV     FSID              FSC
v4 0a69031e  801 0:31    1de70f8892134adb  yes
```

however, when looking into the cache and graveyard directories, they remain empty and the fscache/stats changes minimally.

```
msali014@msali014-VirtualBox:~$ cat /proc/fs/fscache/stats 
FS-Cache statistics
Cookies: idx=3 dat=0 spc=0
Objects: alc=0 nal=0 avl=0 ded=1
ChkAux : non=0 ok=0 upd=0 obs=0
Pages  : mrk=0 unc=0
Acquire: n=3 nul=0 noc=0 ok=3 nbf=0 oom=0
Lookups: n=0 neg=0 pos=0 crt=0 tmo=0
Updates: n=0 nul=0 run=0
Relinqs: n=1 nul=0 wcr=0 rtr=0
AttrChg: n=0 ok=0 nbf=0 oom=0 run=0
Allocs : n=0 ok=0 wt=0 nbf=0 int=0
Allocs : ops=0 owt=0 abt=0
Retrvls: n=0 ok=0 wt=0 nod=0 nbf=0 int=0 oom=0
Retrvls: ops=0 owt=0 abt=0
Stores : n=0 ok=0 agn=0 nbf=0 oom=0
Stores : ops=0 run=0 pgs=0 rxd=0 olm=0
VmScan : nos=0 gon=0 bsy=0 can=0
Ops    : pend=0 run=0 enq=0 can=0 rej=0
Ops    : dfr=0 rel=0 gc=0
CacheOp: alo=0 luo=0 luc=0 gro=0
CacheOp: upo=0 dro=0 pto=0 atc=0 syn=0
CacheOp: rap=0 ras=0 alp=0 als=0 wrp=0 ucp=0 dsp=0
```

The syslog file is as follows

```
Jun 13 14:03:08 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2138]: About to bind cache
Jun 13 14:03:08 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2138]: Bound cache
Jun 13 14:03:08 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2141]: Daemon Started
Jun 13 14:03:08 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2141]: Scan complete
Jun 13 14:03:38 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2141]: Refilling cull table
Jun 13 14:03:38 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2141]: Scan complete
Jun 13 14:04:08 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2141]: Refilling cull table
Jun 13 14:04:08 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2141]: Scan complete
Jun 13 14:04:38 msali014-VirtualBox cachefilesd[2141]: Refilling cull table
```

I have the same settings for the cachefilesd on a desktop computer and the caching works as advertised, just not on the virtual machine.  Any help with this is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like when I installed Ubuntu on the virtual machines (both 32 and 64-bit versions), it was not a "complete" install so the module was compiled, but not implemented fully/correctly.  As mentioned in the question, there would be the corresponding dmesg and syslog files, just no actions taken.  After using kernel 3.9.6 and changing nothing else, the fs-cache worked on the virtual machine.